# How do i add mp4 video into html document

Tags: html, video

I was wondering if you could help me with my related issue. I am trying to add a video to my html doc that i added to a web server. The .html doc is in the same directory as the video i am trying to add. Logically i was just thinking the src would just be the name of the video that is in the same directory. I get the same result if i just add the video name or the path to the video on the server. I am not sure what i can do next to get it running. Here is the src line that i added but still get the same result from the server. When i try it locally on my pc, just putting the name of the video it works.

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://serverIP_or_domain/location_of_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

or

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls autoplay>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: `"I get the same result"` - And what would that result be?

Comment: Your mark-up is fine, you must be pointing to the wrong place on the server - have you tried inspecting with web tools and checking if the video was found in network tab?  If you're referencing at a bad URL you'll likely see 404 in the request header for that file...

Comment: i get "no video with support format and MIME type found"

Comment: on my other browsers i get a blank video box

Comment: its weird because the player comes up but no video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your mark-up, what I would put this problem down to is an incorrect URL, please ensure that you are pointing to A) the right directory or B) the correct request URL.

You can debug this by opening developer tools in Chrome and inspecting the headers of the file in the Network tab:

[image]

In the above example you can see that the request was fine, if you check your headers you'll probably see a 404, meaning your file was not found.

In terms of Mark-Up try:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls="controls" autoplay>
   <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

This will look for `video.mp4` at the root directory, you could also specify something more precise if you have a different document structure: `./public/media/my_video.mp4`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: see the video is the only thing that is not playing because when i put in the path from my website to come up but the video does not play

Comment: So the video loads but doesn't play?

Comment: no the video does not play not to sure if it is a server side problem. I have checked my path like so many time and no dice.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: could it be that the server has not enabled that video type?

Comment: from a server site of things if the video type was not enable would that inhibit me from see the video i posted still?